# How to click a button that has no name or id elements

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I am using selenium with python and i am clicking buttons with this command

```
loginbtn= driver.find_element_by_id('btnLogin').click()
```

My problem now is that i got 2 buttons with no name or id and with exactly same code as the photo below.

[image]

Is there any way to define that i want to click on Submit button or Cancel button?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the below xpath.

For submit:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[./span[text()="Submit"]]').click()
```

For cancel.

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[./span[text()="Cancel"]]').click()
```